# Distributing numbers in groups

Tags: arithmetic

I don't understand how distributive property works in case like this:

$(x_1 \cdot y_1) + (x_2 \cdot y_2) + (x_3 \cdot y_3) + \dots + (x_n \cdot y_n)$

So, how do I calculate this differently? I want to calculate $x$'s and $y$'s separately.

I know this:

> $ 2 \cdot ( 5 + 3 ) = ( 2 \cdot 5 ) + ( 2 \cdot 3 ) $

but why it doesn't work here:

> $ 2 + ( 5 \cdot 3 ) \ne ( 2 \cdot 5 ) + ( 2 \cdot 3 ) $

I hope I'm explaining this right. I'm $11$. Can you explain how this works in simple words? thank you.

Comment: It doesn't work in a case like this.

Comment: Do you mean $x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3+...+x_ny_n$?

Comment: Distributive property only works when you multiply. Since you add 2 to (5*3), distributive property isn't usable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, think of $m\ast n$ as a shorthand for
$$
\underbrace{n+n+\cdots +n}_{m\ \mathrm{times}}.
$$
Then, from your examples,
$$
2\ast(5+3)=2\ast8=8+8=16
$$
and
$$
(2\ast 5)+(2\ast 3)=(5+5)+(3+3)=10+6=16
$$
so the rule works out fine, while
$$
2+(5\ast3)=2+(3+3+3+3+3)=2+15=17
$$
and
$$
(2\ast5)+(2\ast3)=(5+5)+(3+3)=16
$$
so the rule doesn't work.

Another way to look at multiplication is to take $m\ast n$ as the number of squares in a chessboard with $m$ rows and $n$ columns.

This explains right away why $m\ast n=n\ast m$ and the property
$$
a\ast(b+c)=a\ast b+a\ast c
$$
can be understood as joining together two chessboards with the same number of rows, while the other way around has no neat geometric interpretation: when you do
$$
a+(b\ast c)
$$
you are adding $a$ extra squares to a chessboard with $b$ rows and $c$ columns and there's no way to rearrange them in a neatly way that works every time.